Polars pl.when().then().otherwise() in conjunction with first row of group_by object
I have a pl.DataFrame with some columns: level_0, symbol, signal, and a trade. The trade column simply indicates whether to buy or sell the respective symbol ("A" and "B"). It's computed over(["level_0", "symbol"]).
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "level_0": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        "symbol": [ "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", ],
        "signal": [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    }
).with_columns(
    pl.col("signal")
    .diff()
    .replace(old=0, new=None)
    .over(["level_0", "symbol"])
    .alias("trade")
)

shape: (16, 4)
┌─────────┬────────┬────────┬───────┐
│ level_0 ┆ symbol ┆ signal ┆ trade │
│ ---     ┆ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---   │
│ i64     ┆ str    ┆ i64    ┆ i64   │
╞═════════╪════════╪════════╪═══════╡
│ 0       ┆ A      ┆ 1      ┆ null  │
│ 0       ┆ A      ┆ 0      ┆ -1    │
│ 0       ┆ A      ┆ 1      ┆ 1     │
│ 0       ┆ A      ┆ 1      ┆ null  │
│ 0       ┆ B      ┆ 0      ┆ null  │
│ 0       ┆ B      ┆ 1      ┆ 1     │
│ 0       ┆ B      ┆ 1      ┆ null  │
│ 0       ┆ B      ┆ 0      ┆ -1    │
│ 1       ┆ A      ┆ 0      ┆ null  │
│ 1       ┆ A      ┆ 0      ┆ null  │
│ 1       ┆ A      ┆ 0      ┆ null  │
│ 1       ┆ A      ┆ 1      ┆ 1     │
│ 1       ┆ B      ┆ 1      ┆ null  │
│ 1       ┆ B      ┆ 1      ┆ null  │
│ 1       ┆ B      ┆ 0      ┆ -1    │
│ 1       ┆ B      ┆ 0      ┆ null  │
└─────────┴────────┴────────┴───────┘

So far, so good. The only thing is that the first row of each group (["level_0", "symbol"]) isn't correct. I would like to change the null values in the trade column according to the following rule:

If the signal column holds a value different from 0 in the respective first row of each group, this value should be copied to the respective first row of each group of the trade column.
If the signal column holds a value equal to 0 in the respective first row of each group, the value of the respective first row of each group of the trade column stays unchanged.

To put it differently, I am looking to change the null values in the first row of each group in the trade column whenever there is a value in the signal column that is different from zero.
Here's what I'm looking for:
shape: (16, 4)
┌─────────┬────────┬────────┬───────┐
│ level_0 ┆ symbol ┆ signal ┆ trade │
│ ---     ┆ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---   │
│ i64     ┆ str    ┆ i64    ┆ i64   │
╞═════════╪════════╪════════╪═══════╡
│ 0       ┆ A      ┆ 1      ┆ 1     │ <-- copied value from signal column
│ 0       ┆ A      ┆ 0      ┆ -1    │
│ 0       ┆ A      ┆ 1      ┆ 1     │
│ 0       ┆ A      ┆ 1      ┆ null  │
│ 0       ┆ B      ┆ 0      ┆ null  │ <-- value stays unchanged
│ 0       ┆ B      ┆ 1      ┆ 1     │
│ 0       ┆ B      ┆ 1      ┆ null  │
│ 0       ┆ B      ┆ 0      ┆ -1    │
│ 1       ┆ A      ┆ 0      ┆ null  │ <-- value stays unchanged
│ 1       ┆ A      ┆ 0      ┆ null  │
│ 1       ┆ A      ┆ 0      ┆ null  │
│ 1       ┆ A      ┆ 1      ┆ 1     │
│ 1       ┆ B      ┆ 1      ┆ 1     │ <-- copied value from signal column
│ 1       ┆ B      ┆ 1      ┆ null  │
│ 1       ┆ B      ┆ 0      ┆ -1    │
│ 1       ┆ B      ┆ 0      ┆ null  │
└─────────┴────────┴────────┴───────┘


You can create a "group key" from multiple columns/expressions using a  pl.struct()
.is_first_distinct() can then be used to identify the first row of each "group".
with pl.Config(tbl_rows=16):
    df.with_columns(
       pl.when(pl.struct("level_0", "symbol").is_first_distinct(), pl.col.signal == 1)
         .then(1)
         .otherwise(pl.col.trade)
         .alias("trade")
    )

shape: (16, 4)
┌─────────┬────────┬────────┬───────┐
│ level_0 ┆ symbol ┆ signal ┆ trade │
│ ---     ┆ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---   │
│ i64     ┆ str    ┆ i64    ┆ i64   │
╞═════════╪════════╪════════╪═══════╡
│ 0       ┆ A      ┆ 1      ┆ 1     │
│ 0       ┆ A      ┆ 0      ┆ -1    │
│ 0       ┆ A      ┆ 1      ┆ 1     │
│ 0       ┆ A      ┆ 1      ┆ null  │
│ 0       ┆ B      ┆ 0      ┆ null  │
│ 0       ┆ B      ┆ 1      ┆ 1     │
│ 0       ┆ B      ┆ 1      ┆ null  │
│ 0       ┆ B      ┆ 0      ┆ -1    │
│ 1       ┆ A      ┆ 0      ┆ null  │
│ 1       ┆ A      ┆ 0      ┆ null  │
│ 1       ┆ A      ┆ 0      ┆ null  │
│ 1       ┆ A      ┆ 1      ┆ 1     │
│ 1       ┆ B      ┆ 1      ┆ 1     │
│ 1       ┆ B      ┆ 1      ┆ null  │
│ 1       ┆ B      ┆ 0      ┆ -1    │
│ 1       ┆ B      ┆ 0      ┆ null  │
└─────────┴────────┴────────┴───────┘


Update per follow-up question:

check if signal in the first row of each group is different from zero, but I then replace the trade value of the following row

You can .shift() over groups to move forward/backward by N rows.
df.with_columns(
   pl.all_horizontal(
      pl.struct("level_0", "symbol").is_first_distinct(),
      pl.col("signal") == 1
   )
#   .shift()
#   .over("level_0", "symbol")
   .alias("change me")
)

shape: (16, 5)
┌─────────┬────────┬────────┬───────┬───────────┐
│ level_0 ┆ symbol ┆ signal ┆ trade ┆ change me │
│ ---     ┆ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---   ┆ ---       │
│ i64     ┆ str    ┆ i64    ┆ i64   ┆ bool      │
╞═════════╪════════╪════════╪═══════╪═══════════╡
│ 0       ┆ A      ┆ 1      ┆ null  ┆ true      │
│ 0       ┆ A      ┆ 0      ┆ -1    ┆ false     │ # <- shift to here
│ 0       ┆ A      ┆ 1      ┆ 1     ┆ false     │
│ 0       ┆ A      ┆ 1      ┆ null  ┆ false     │
│ 0       ┆ B      ┆ 0      ┆ null  ┆ false     │
│ 0       ┆ B      ┆ 1      ┆ 1     ┆ false     │ # <- shift to here
│ 0       ┆ B      ┆ 1      ┆ null  ┆ false     │
│ 0       ┆ B      ┆ 0      ┆ -1    ┆ false     │
│ 1       ┆ A      ┆ 0      ┆ null  ┆ false     │
│ 1       ┆ A      ┆ 0      ┆ null  ┆ false     │ # <- shift to here
│ 1       ┆ A      ┆ 0      ┆ null  ┆ false     │
│ 1       ┆ A      ┆ 1      ┆ 1     ┆ false     │
│ 1       ┆ B      ┆ 1      ┆ null  ┆ true      │
│ 1       ┆ B      ┆ 1      ┆ null  ┆ false     │ # <- shift to here
│ 1       ┆ B      ┆ 0      ┆ -1    ┆ false     │
│ 1       ┆ B      ┆ 0      ┆ null  ┆ false     │
└─────────┴────────┴────────┴───────┴───────────┘

Used within when/then:
df.with_columns(
   pl.when(
      pl.all_horizontal(
         pl.struct("level_0", "symbol").is_first_distinct(),
         pl.col("signal") == 1
      )
      .shift()
      .over("level_0", "symbol")
   )
   .then(1)
   .otherwise(pl.col("trade"))
   .alias("new_trade")
)

shape: (16, 5)
┌─────────┬────────┬────────┬───────┬───────────┐
│ level_0 ┆ symbol ┆ signal ┆ trade ┆ new_trade │
│ ---     ┆ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---   ┆ ---       │
│ i64     ┆ str    ┆ i64    ┆ i64   ┆ i64       │
╞═════════╪════════╪════════╪═══════╪═══════════╡
│ 0       ┆ A      ┆ 1      ┆ null  ┆ null      │
│ 0       ┆ A      ┆ 0      ┆ -1    ┆ 1         │ # CHANGE
│ 0       ┆ A      ┆ 1      ┆ 1     ┆ 1         │
│ 0       ┆ A      ┆ 1      ┆ null  ┆ null      │
│ 0       ┆ B      ┆ 0      ┆ null  ┆ null      │
│ 0       ┆ B      ┆ 1      ┆ 1     ┆ 1         │
│ 0       ┆ B      ┆ 1      ┆ null  ┆ null      │
│ 0       ┆ B      ┆ 0      ┆ -1    ┆ -1        │
│ 1       ┆ A      ┆ 0      ┆ null  ┆ null      │
│ 1       ┆ A      ┆ 0      ┆ null  ┆ null      │
│ 1       ┆ A      ┆ 0      ┆ null  ┆ null      │
│ 1       ┆ A      ┆ 1      ┆ 1     ┆ 1         │
│ 1       ┆ B      ┆ 1      ┆ null  ┆ null      │
│ 1       ┆ B      ┆ 1      ┆ null  ┆ 1         │ # CHANGE
│ 1       ┆ B      ┆ 0      ┆ -1    ┆ -1        │
│ 1       ┆ B      ┆ 0      ┆ null  ┆ null      │
└─────────┴────────┴────────┴───────┴───────────┘


Follow-up question: What if I need to change not the first row in every group but the second row? That is, I still check if signal in the first row of each group is different from zero, but I then replace the trade value of the following row?

@Andi .shift() + .over() is one way to move around - I've added an example.
